# LinkedIn API Rate Limit Criteria

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am building a tool that integrates with LinkedIn API.

During testing I hit "RateLimitExceeded", and I have not been able to use the API now for a few days.

What exactly is the criteria for this? I have looked ALL OVER and have found no documentation.

Comment: what is the code you are executing?  Sounds like you are trying to pull back too much data

Comment: LinkedIn reported "Service Unavailable" after we had only about 2k "Log-in with LinkedIn" requests within ~15 minutes. Bonus: The same happened with Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you can't find this. I'll look to make this more visible:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/throttle-limits

Comment: The above link is broken. It seems linkedin has moved it again. Please check the answer below by @Kat that has the correct link as of today.

Comment: Link brings me to a page that says it is restricted and I must log in, once I log in it just brings me back to the home page

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else finds this on Google, the documentation has moved to:

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits

Comment: This belongs to a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @b.enoit.be Thanks - I don't usually add anything here, as you can probably tell. Should I delete and repost as a comment, or was that just feedback for next time?

Comment: Oh, apparently I can't comment until I have 50 reputation anyhow. So... not sure what I'm supposed to do, sorry.

Comment: That's fine like that. But with an accepted answer, you have less chances to have people scrolling to your answer. And for further information a link only answer is usually viewed on Stack Overflow as poor quality answer (cf : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: And that is why, even if the accepted answer is a link only answer, it is not relevant anymore and why yours is now more relevant... but could get even more if you edit it to make it a real answer documented with a link. :)

Comment: The above link emits a `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: Especially because this link is now ALSO broken. Cmon stackoverflow, you're better than this. If I find the answer, I'll actually post the info to SO...

Comment: Throttle limits are now documented per API endpoint. Eg. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: @LucasBonner sort of, there is no information on the limits for getting comments / likes on comments: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#get_update_comments

Comment: @linkedin Any comments? Is there a default throttle limit when one isn't otherwise specified? Nhttps://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api